# MongoDB bson.M query

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to query using bison all JSON data in MongoDB with two fields but am getting null as result.

```
{
        "allowedList": [
            {
                "List": [
                    {
                        "allow": {
                            "ss": 1,
                        },
                        "Information": [
                            {
                                "Id": "Id1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        }
```

I was able to filter all using the MongoDB at command line using

```
    db.slicedb.find({"allowedList.List.allow.ss":1,"allowedList.List.Information.nsiId":"Id-Id21"}) 
but using 

query := bson.M{"allowedList.List.allow": bson.M{"ss": sst}, "allowedList.List.Information": bson.M{"Id": Id}}
```

sst and Id are integer and string input to the query function

```
err := db.C(COLLECTION).Find(query).All(&specificSlices)
```

but is not working, am getting null even though there are json data that match the two field. Can someone help point out what was wrong with my query?

Server and database config

```
type SliceDataAccess struct {
        Server   string
        Database string
   }



var db *mgo.Database

const (
    COLLECTION = "slicedb"
  )
```

Establish a connection to database

```
func (m *SliceDataAccess) Connect() {
        session, err := mgo.DialWithTimeout(m.Server, 20*time.Second)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            db = session.DB(m.Database)
        }
```

Structs fields

```
type InstanceInfo struct {
     ID     string    `json:"nfId" bson:"_id"`
     AllowedList []AllowedNssai `json:"allowedList" bson:"allowedList"`

   }

type AllowedNssai struct {
        List []AllowedSnssai `json:"List,omitempty" bson:"List"`
        ...
     }

type AllowedSnssai struct {
      Allow *Snssai `json:"allow,omitempty" bson:"allow"`
      Information []NsiInformation `json:"Information,omitempty" bson:"Information"`

  }

type NsiInformation struct {
      Id string `json:"Id" bson:"Id"`
   }




type Snssai struct {
      Ss int32  `json:"sst" bson:"ss"`

   }
```

Query function defined

```
func (m *SliceDataAccess) FindAll(sst int32, nsiId string ([]InstanceInfo, error) {
var specificSlices []InstanceInfo

query := bson.M{"allowedList.List.allow": bson.M{"ss": sst}, "allowedList.List.Information": bson.M{"Id": nsiId}}

err := db.C(COLLECTION).Find(query).All(&specificSlices)
if err != nil {
       return specificSlices, err
       }
        return specificSlices, nil
     }
```

HTTP handler function for request and response

```
func AvailabilityGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) 
            var slice InstanceInfo
            err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&slice)
            if err != nil {
                respondWithError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Object body not well decoded")
                return
            }
            sst := slice.AllowedList[0].List[0].Allow.Sst
            nsiId := slice.AllowedList[0].List[0].Information[0].Id

            specificSlices, err := da.FindAll(sst, nsiId)

            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(specificSlices)
        }
```

Attached is my the full go code i have done.

Comment: Include your Go code. It's impossible to find a bug we can't see.

Comment: Your working command line example uses `nsiId`, is this a typo? it should be `Id`.

Comment: yes it should be Id, a typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

this worked

query := bson.M{"allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList.allowedSnssai.sst": sst, "allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList.nsiInformationList.nsiId": nsiId}